# move desktop icons onto windows form when drag and drop?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, drag-and-drop

im kind of confused, i used codes that enable you to drag and drop desktop icons/files/folders on windows forms, but how to show it inside the windows forms and the icon is still executable?

Comment: i'm confused too - what are you trying to show on the form?

Comment: When you receive the object via drag/drop, it becomes your responsibility to show it in your window in whatever form you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time GridControl is used to display the files.Its easy to display information about files in that way.But the best way to shows files depends on what do you want to do with the files.If you elaborate your problem then we can suggest.